# Assert ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext() in the StepVerifier of my WebFilter Webflux

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am migrating our security library which is Servlet based.

I need to use ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext() instead of SecurityContextHolder.getContext().

I have a WebFLux WebFilter that modifies the Authentication.

```
  @Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {        
...
   return chain.filter(exchange).subscriberContext(ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.withAuthentication(authentication));

}
```

I would like to assert the Authentication in ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().
StepVerifier.create(filter.filter(MockServerWebExchange.from(request), filterChain)).expectNext(...).verifyComplete();

No matter what I try, the context is null because I have to subscribe to the Mono returned by ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().

I tried ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().block() without success.

May be the way I try to test it is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do it is to use the WebFilterChain which is basically a lambda.

So we can have a WebFilterChain : (exchange) -> Mono.empty()

But we need a lambda that will use ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext() instead of Mono.empty();

The result looks like :

```
    var request = MockServerHttpRequest
            .get("/api/test")
            .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + jwt);

    var exchange = MockServerWebExchange.from(request);

    StepVerifier.create(filter.filter(
            exchange,
            it -> ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                    .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
                    .map(JWTAuthentication.class::cast)
                    .doOnSuccess(auth -> assertThat(auth.getUserId()).isEqualTo("username"))
                    .doOnSuccess(auth -> assertThat(auth.getJwt()).isEqualTo(jwt))
                    .doOnSuccess(auth -> assertThat(auth.getSubscriptions()).isEmpty())
                    .then()
    )).verifyComplete();
```